# Combining an IF statement with current query

Tags: mysql

I've got the following query that's finding all subscribers between a certain date:

```
SELECT s.id as 'Subscription ID', s.customer_id as 'Customer ID', s.start_date as 'Start Date', s.status as 'Current Status', l.date 'Cancellation Date'
FROM subscriptions as s

LEFT JOIN subscriptionlog as l ON s.id=l.subscription_id

WHERE s.start_date >= 1559347200 
AND s.start_date <= 1596239999
```

I've added the last column "Cancellation date" where I want to find the following:

```
l.event = 'subscription_cancelled'
```

If that exists for a subscriber can it output l.date but if it can't find it, can the column be left blank for that line? How can I incorporate an IF statement?

Comment: Can you add sample data, expected result and current result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for `CASE` clause. You can put it in your select clause for if-else display issues. You can also put it in your WHERE clause for a more robust filter.

In your case:

```
SELECT 
    s.id as 'Subscription ID', 
    s.customer_id as 'Customer ID', 
    s.start_date as 'Start Date', 
    s.status as 'Current Status', 

    CASE
        WHEN l.event = 'subscription_cancelled'
        THEN l.date
        ELSE NULL
    END as 'Cancellation Date'

FROM subscriptions as s

LEFT JOIN subscriptionlog as l ON s.id=l.subscription_id

WHERE s.start_date >= 1559347200 
AND s.start_date <= 1596239999
```

Comment: That's great, how would I do it via the where statement?